# HTML Cellrenderer Bug

Tags: tablecellrenderer, qooxdoo

i am trying to set Rich Text in a Table after an Event. The Problem is, that the HTML Tags are only recognized after i clicked on the Header or resize the Table. I did a little [Playground Example](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22%252F%252F%2520Create%2520a%2520button%250Avar%2520button1%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522First%2520Button%2522%252C%2520%2522icon%252F22%252Fapps%252Finternet-web-browser.png%2522)%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520Document%2520is%2520the%2520application%2520root%250Avar%2520doc%2520%253D%2520this.getRoot()%253B%250A%250Adoc.add(button1%252C%250A%257B%250A%2520%2520left%2520%253A%2520200%252C%250A%2520%2520top%2520%2520%253A%25200%250A%257D)%253B%250A%250Avar%2520table%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.Table(null)%253B%250A%250Adoc.add(table)%253B%250A%250Abutton1.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520table.setFocusedCell()%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520tableModel%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.model.Simple()%253B%250A%2509tableModel.setEditable(false)%253B%250A%2509tableModel.setColumns(%255B%2522test%2522%255D)%253B%250A%2509tableModel.setData(%255B%255B%2522%253Cb%253Etest%253C%252Fb%253E%2522%255D%255D)%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509%250A%2509table.setTableModel(tableModel)%253B%250A%250A%2509table.setColumnWidth(0%252C%2520200)%253B%250A%250A%2509var%2520tableColumnModel%2520%253D%2520table.getTableColumnModel()%253B%250A%250A%2509for%2520(var%2520i%2520%253D%25200%253B%2520i%2520%253C%25201%253B%2520i%252B%252B)%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509tableColumnModel.setDataCellRenderer(i%252C%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Html())%253B%250A%2509%257D%250A%257D)%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509%250A%2509%2509%2509%250A%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)
After clicking Button the data is loaded with HTML Tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the cell renderer before to load the data :

```js
var table = new qx.ui.table.Table(null);

button1.addListener("execute", function(e) {

    var tableColumnModel = table.getTableColumnModel();
    tableColumnModel.setDataCellRenderer(0, new qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Html());

    tableModel.setData([["<b>test</b>"],["<i>test</i>"]]);
});
```

Here is the full [playground example](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22%252F%252F%2520Create%2520a%2520button%250Avar%2520button1%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522First%2520Button%2522%252C%2520%2522icon%252F22%252Fapps%252Finternet-web-browser.png%2522)%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520Document%2520is%2520the%2520application%2520root%250Avar%2520doc%2520%253D%2520this.getRoot()%253B%250A%250Adoc.add(button1%252C%250A%257B%250A%2520%2520left%2520%253A%2520200%252C%250A%2520%2520top%2520%2520%253A%25200%250A%257D)%253B%250A%250Avar%2520table%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.Table(null)%253B%250A%250Adoc.add(table)%253B%250A%250Abutton1.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520table.setFocusedCell()%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520tableModel%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.model.Simple()%253B%250A%2509tableModel.setEditable(false)%253B%250A%2509tableModel.setColumns(%255B%2522test%2522%255D)%253B%250A%2509%250A%2509%2509%2509%250A%2509table.setTableModel(tableModel)%253B%250A%250A%2509table.setColumnWidth(0%252C%2520200)%253B%250A%250A%2509var%2520tableColumnModel%2520%253D%2520table.getTableColumnModel()%253B%250A%250A%2509for%2520(var%2520i%2520%253D%25200%253B%2520i%2520%253C%25201%253B%2520i%252B%252B)%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509tableColumnModel.setDataCellRenderer(i%252C%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Html())%253B%250A%2509%257D%250A%2509%250A%2509tableModel.setData(%255B%255B%2522%253Cb%253Etest%253C%252Fb%253E%2522%255D%252C%255B%2522%253Ci%253Etest%253C%252Fi%253E%2522%255D%255D)%253B%250A%257D)%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509%250A%2509%2509%2509%250A%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D).

Comment: Thats right but the Problem is that i dont know how many columns i have before i get the Data.